# Object Oriented PHP Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I've never tried OO PHP before so I decided to make a simple CMS to learn more. I am having a problem loading values into a multi-dimensional array.

```
class Article {
  private $index = 0;
  private $article;

  public function Article() {
   $get_articles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles`");
   while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($get_articles)) {
    echo $result["article"];

    $this->article[$index]["Tags"] = $result["tags"];
    $this->article[$index]["Categories"] = $result["categories"];
    $this->article[$index]["Date"] = $result["date"];
    $this->article[$index]["Article"] = $result["article"];
    $this->article[$index]["URL"] = $result["url"];

    $index++;
   }
  }

  public function getArticle($articleID) {
   return $this->article[$articleID]["Article"];
  }

  public function getTags($articleNumber) {

  }

  public function getCategories($articleNumber) {

  }

  public function getDate($articleNumber) {

  }
 }
```

The line `echo $result["article"]` outputs the one and only article value just  fine, but apparently doesn't put it into the array?

```
$art = new Article();
echo $art->getArticle(0);
```

This doesn't output the article however. Would someone so kindly point out my noob mistake?

Comment: Where is `$index` defined in the `Article()` method?

Comment: He made it a global, it's on the first line of his code

Comment: *(sidenote)* You are encouraged to use the more feature-rich `mysqli` (*i* for improved) extension over the `mysql` extension. Also using the class name for the constructor instead of `__construct` is PHP4 syntax and will (as of PHP5.3.3) no longer work when using namespaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't initialize your array.

```
$this->article = array();

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($get_articles)) {
  $this->article[$index] = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably should define your `$index` variable before using it in the loop. Maybe set it to the primary key field you retrieved from your query.

```
<?php
$index = $result['id'];
$this->article[$index]['tags'] = ...
```

You also need to initialize the `$article` member variable.

```
<?php
class Article {
    private $article = array();
```

Remember that you define member variables within a class to be referenced via `$this->` so you also don't need to define `private $index = 0;` in your class definition. Just define it inside the method.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice you used `$this->article` but not `$this->index` if you want to keep track of the length for the life of the object you'll need to replace `$index` with `$this->index`